# How to make fixed column for products list in woocommerce?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have a problem about making fixed column for products list in woocommerce with my custom theme, like a iphone 6s product cannot have same box size with other in screenshot below:
[image: box size]

**style.css**

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
    width: 30.75%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1px 0 1.992em 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 6px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: Can you link to your page or a demo of the issue?

Comment: Just add some `min-height` to your product box. That way they'll all have same initial height.

Comment: I also have the same problem, did u ever get to solve this?

Comment: @manojKumar please check out [this link](http://dev.galerigadget.com/shop/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add DIV tag for your Price row and give `min-height` to DIV tag like

```
<div class="price">Rp 12,000.000</div>
```

Style

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product{ min-height:100px }
```